# Different versions of jQuery causing a some problems

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

When ever I send back a JSON array via AJAX; one of the objects will be "error":true/false. It worked fine in version 1.4.2; but since then I have changed to 1.6.2. On 1.6.2 I have built modal script but when I put it live I was getting an error with the JSON array saying that property "error" does not exist, or something along those lines, when it does.

I tried changing back to previous version of 1.4.2 but then I had a problem with the modal; mentioning a problem to do with 'handle' somewhere on the jQuery script itself.

I don't know if anyone has experienced the same problem but does anyone know how to fix it?

Many thanks

Edit:
It return a string like this: {"error":false, "data":[{"element":"currentweather","html":"Rain"},{"element":"currenttemp","html":"22°C"}]}
I'm not sure if it's anything to do with the array?

Comment: It returns a string like this: {"error":false, "data":[{"element":"currentweather","html":"Rain"},{"element":"currenttemp","html":"22&deg;C"}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is weird; server side if I put json_encode an already json encoded array it works!
i.e. json_encode(json_encode($json));

Answer (score 1):

Might seem silly, but try to add the `"error"` property yourself?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the JSON error by double-quoting the value:

```
"error": "true/false"
```

since JSON is parsed in a strict manner.

Comment: I think that he meant that the `"error"` property is a boolean, having a value of true or false.